# How to read/update Azure B2C MFA phone number using Graph API (or any other means)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to retreive/change the MFA number on a B2C account programatically. I don't really mind how its done, and I am aware of this SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858874/243905 but that was asked a long time ago and I had hoped it was different now.

I find the B2C docs are a bit lacking in clarity on this information, and **although I am able to query the users using the method detailed here**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet 
the object that is returned **does not return the MFA details**. 
Is this possible through any means?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481718/185123

Answer (score 0):

strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber can be issued in the resulting token, however it  can't be edited using graph, for the moment. It's expected this capability will be available during the 2nd half of 2018.

Comment: can it be reset, such that the user would have to update on their next login?

Comment: Yes. Check this user case I have created some time ago. https://github.com/marcelodiiorio/My-Azure-AD-B2C-use-cases/tree/master/Simple%20method%20to%20prevent%20users%20registering%20a%20new%20phone%20number%20during%20sign-in

You have to play with

<Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">false</Item>

Comment: @MarceloP.DiIorio-MSFT So has this capability been added yet.

Comment: @MarceloP.DiIorio-MSFT How about now?

Comment: @MarceloP.DiIorio-MSFT how about now?

Answer (score 0):

As of today this appears to be working for Azure B2C. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/phoneauthenticationmethod?view=graph-rest-beta)

There is an extra permission that the token will need.  `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All`